# Collision rate of `rand64()` function in Clickhouse

Tags: statistics, clickhouse

I'm planning to use `Int64()` for primary key and `rand64()` for it's generation. I need uniqueness (no collisions) and I'm planning to have billions of rows. I cannot use UUID for other reasons.

What is the probability of it to generate collision? I know that UUID is pretty sure in that regards so wondering how it compares to it.
I see that it uses **linear congruential generator** but there is not much information on the function other than that (what parameters it uses which can affect [period length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length)).

Thanks!

Comment: [Random number generators](https://imgur.com/uR4WuQ0) might give "collisions". Don't use it to create unique keys. I don't know about Clickhouse, but most other database-system have actual facilities to create properly unique id's.

Comment: Yes, but people still use UUID generators for that fairly frequently as it usually uses 128 bits of information which is good enough ("the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion" from wiki).
If we can use Birthday’s paradox to calculate this then 64 bits is def useless / to small as it has high chance of collisions when speaking on billions of rows, but I'm not sure if I can calculate it with that.

Comment: Well, you already know that LCG64 won't generate collisions for a given set of multiplier and carry parameters (Hull-Dobell theorem). So LCG64(row index) should work. You could write it youself

Answer (score 0):

Try to UInt64 instead of Int64
and use snowflake id generation

```sql
create function toSnowflake64 as (dt,ch) ->
  bitOr(dateTime64ToSnowflake(dt),
   bitAnd(bitAnd(ch,0x3FFFFF)+
      bitAnd(bitShiftRight(ch, 20),0x3FFFFF)+
      bitAnd(bitShiftRight(ch, 40),0x3FFFFF),
      0x3FFFFF) 
  );

create function toSnowflake as (dt,ch) ->
  bitOr(dateTimeToSnowflake(dt),
   bitAnd(bitAnd(ch,0xFFFFFFFF)+
      bitAnd(bitShiftRight(ch, 32),0xFFFFFFFF),
      0xFFFFFFFF) 
  );
    
with cityHash64('asdfsdnfs;n') as ch,
  now64() as dt
select dt,
  hex(toSnowflake64(dt,ch) as sn) ,
  snowflakeToDateTime64(sn);

with cityHash64('asdfsdnfs;n') as ch,
  now() as dt
select dt,
  hex(toSnowflake(dt,ch) as sn) ,
  snowflakeToDateTime(sn);



CREATE TABLE t (id UInt64 DEFAULT toSnowflake64(now64(), cityHash64(hostName())), s LowCardinality(String)) ENGINE=MergeTree() ORDER BY tuple();

INSERT INTO t(s) SELECT toString(number) FROM numbers(10);

SELECT * FROM t;
```